# Override a custom function value

Tags: php

I' am currently stuck at a point where am overriding a function value using a custom code with "**call_user_func**". The function name is "**admin_branding**" which can cater for other function to override it's default value.

**Usage**

```
<?php echo admin_branding(); ?>
```

From the above function, the result is "**Example 1**" but the outcome should be "**Example 2**" because am override its value using the "**add_filter**"

**PHP Codes**

```
/* Custom function with its custom value */
function custom_admin_branding(){
    return "Example 2";
}

/* Default function with its default value */
function admin_branding( $arg = '' ){
    if( $arg ){ $var = $arg();
    } else { $var = "Example 1"; }
    return $var;
}

/* Call User function which override the function value */
function add_filter( $hook = '', $function = '' ){
    call_user_func( $hook , "$function" );
}

/* Passing function value to override and argument as custom function */
add_filter( "admin_branding", "custom_admin_branding" );
```

A very example is how WordPress does using their custom **add_filter** function.

Comment: Are you asking how to unset a function?

Comment: Not actually, I' am trying to use the add_filter function like WordPress does.

Comment: Why do you think that you're overwriting "its value" (of `admin_branding()`)? `call_user_func` will just immediately invoke `custom_admin_branding` and not replace anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me try another way.

Comment: PHP does not support overrides for functions like other languages. Alternatives to get around this would be to create a new section of  functions inside a new namespace, and create a function in the main  namespace to handle routing to the new namespace with the *Overrides*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mimic WordPress (wouldn't recommend this though):

```
$filters = array();

function add_filter($hook, $functionName){
    global $filters;
    if (!isset($filters[$hook])) {
        $filters[$hook] = array();
    }
    $filters[$hook][] = $functionName;
}

function apply_filters($hook, $value) {
    global $filters;
    if (isset($filters[$hook])) {
        foreach ($filters[$hook] as $function) {
            $value = call_user_func($function, $value);
        }
    }
    return $value;
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------

function custom_admin_branding($originalBranding) {
    return "Example 2";
}

function admin_branding() {
    $defaultValue = "Example 1";
    return apply_filters("admin_branding", $defaultValue); // apply filters here!
}

echo admin_branding(); // before adding the filter -> Example 1
add_filter("admin_branding", "custom_admin_branding");
echo admin_branding(); // after adding the filter -> Example 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You may check http://php.net/manual/de/function.call-user-func.php from the PhP manual.
It does not "overwrite" something, actually it just invokes your first function.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, I have drawn up a very. Very basic scenario on how I would implement such a thing:

**Index.php**

```
include "OverRides.php";
function Test(){
    return true;
}
function Call_OverRides($NameSpace, $FunctionName, $Value = array()){
    $Function_Call = call_user_func($NameSpace.'\\'.$FunctionName,$Value);
    return $Function_Call; // return the returns from your overrides

}
```

**OverRides.php**

```
namespace OverRides;
    function Test($Test){
        return $Test;
    }
```

<s>*Not actively tested, concept flows through implementation though*</s>

**Debugging:**

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump(Test()); // Output: bool(true)
echo "<br><br>";
var_dump(Call_OverRides('OverRides','Test',"Parameter")); // Output: string(9) "Parameter"
```

Comment: If further explanation is required on the working structure/back-end processing. I'd be happy to provide on request